# How to use Segmented Control in Multiplatform App in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Here is so far what i tried. I am trying to load it programmatically.I am writing this code in the multi-platform project. As shown in the image attached.

Img here.

[image]

```cs
var layout = new StackLayout()
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
    Spacing = 20,
    Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0)
};

if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
{
    var segmentControl = new UISegmentedControl();
    segmentControl.Frame = new CGRect(20, 20, 280, 40);
    segmentControl.InsertSegment("One", 0, false);
    segmentControl.InsertSegment("Two", 1, false);
    segmentControl.SelectedSegment = 1;
    segmentControl.ValueChanged += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        var selectedSegmentId = (sender as UISegmentedControl).SelectedSegment;
        await MainPage.DisplayAlert($"Native Segmented Control Clicked {selectedSegmentId}",
                                                  "Whoa!!!!!!", "OK");
    };
    layout.Children.Add(segmentControl);
}
```

Is it possible to do like this? Or custom render is the only solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use SegmentedControl in iOS app written with Xamarin.Forms.

The code that you are asking about will be a good fit if you will use [shared project approach with Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/).

In that case you need to wrap iOS-specific code in conditional directive `#if __IOS__` (`#if __ANDROID__` for Android-specific code)

```cs
var layout = new StackLayout()
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
    Spacing = 20,
    Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0)
};

#if __IOS__
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
{
    var segmentControl = new UISegmentedControl();
    segmentControl.Frame = new CGRect(20, 20, 280, 40);
    segmentControl.InsertSegment("One", 0, false);
    segmentControl.InsertSegment("Two", 1, false);
    segmentControl.SelectedSegment = 1;
    segmentControl.ValueChanged += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        var selectedSegmentId = (sender as UISegmentedControl).SelectedSegment;
        await MainPage.DisplayAlert($"Native Segmented Control Clicked {selectedSegmentId}",
                                                  "Whoa!!!!!!", "OK");
    };
    layout.Children.Add(segmentControl);
}
#endif
```

There is a good example showing how to use UISegmentedControl with Xamarin.Forms from James Montemagno [Embedding Native Controls into Xamarin.Forms](https://blog.xamarin.com/embedding-native-controls-into-xamarin-forms/)

**However**, it looks like you have you solution based on PCL approach.

When using [Portable Class Library approach with Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/), you will have to create a custom control (check [this simple example about UISegmentedControl](https://blog.falafel.com/xamarin-forms-segmented-control/)) or use 3rd party controls like [SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin](https://github.com/alexrainman/SegmentedControl)

Comment: @valdetero Thank you for explaining it. I am able to render the segmented control into the view now. But i want to do it using the code behind. How can i create the below code in the code behind?
<controls:SegmentedControl>
    <controls:SegmentedControl.Children>
     <controls:SegmentedControlOption Text="India" />
        <controls:SegmentedControlOption Text="Usa" />
     <controls:SegmentedControlOption Text="Other" />
    </controls:SegmentedControl.Children>
   </controls:SegmentedControl>

Comment: I just used below code and it worked like charm!!!
SegmentedControl objSeg = new SegmentedControl();
      SegmentedControlOption segp1 = new SegmentedControlOption();
      segp1.Text = "India";
      SegmentedControlOption segp2 = new SegmentedControlOption();
      segp1.Text = "Usa";
      SegmentedControlOption segp3 = new SegmentedControlOption();
      segp1.Text = "Other";
      objSeg.Children.Add(segp1);
      objSeg.Children.Add(segp2);
      objSeg.Children.Add(segp3);

      layout.Children.Add(objSeg);